# Is it possible to use only a single property of an external Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm using semantic-ui-react, a UI library for React that includes Typescript typings.

Here's an example of one of their type files: Flag.d.ts.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface FlagProps {
  [key: string]: any;

  /** An element type to render as (string or function). */
  as?: any;

  /** Additional classes. */
  className?: string;

  /** Flag name, can use the two digit country code, the full name, or a common alias. */
  name: 'ad' | 'andorra' | 'ae' | 'united arab emirates' | 'uae' | 'af' | 'afghanistan' | 'ag' | 'antigua' | 'ai' |
    'anguilla' | 'al' | 'albania' | 'am' | 'armenia' | 'an' | 'netherlands antilles' | 'ao' | 'angola' | 'ar' |
    'argentina' | 'as' | 'american samoa' | 'at' | 'austria' | 'au' | 'australia' | 'aw' | 'aruba' | 'ax' |
    'aland islands' | 'az' | 'azerbaijan' | 'ba' | 'bosnia' | 'bb' | 'barbados' | 'bd' | 'bangladesh' | 'be' |
    'belgium' | 'bf' | 'burkina faso' | 'bg' | 'bulgaria' | 'bh' | 'bahrain' | 'bi' | 'burundi' | 'bj' | 'benin' |
    'bm' | 'bermuda' | 'bn' | 'brunei' | 'bo' | 'bolivia' | 'br' | 'brazil' | 'bs' | 'bahamas' | 'bt' | 'bhutan' |
    'bv' | 'bouvet island' | 'bw' | 'botswana' | 'by' | 'belarus' | 'bz' | 'belize' | 'ca' | 'canada' | 'cc' |
    'cocos islands' | 'cd' | 'congo' | 'cf' | 'central african republic' | 'cg' | 'congo brazzaville' | 'ch' |
    'switzerland' | 'ci' | 'cote divoire' | 'ck' | 'cook islands' | 'cl' | 'chile' | 'cm' | 'cameroon' | 'cn' |
    'china' | 'co' | 'colombia' | 'cr' | 'costa rica' | 'cs' | 'cu' | 'cuba' | 'cv' | 'cape verde' | 'cx' |
    'christmas island' | 'cy' | 'cyprus' | 'cz' | 'czech republic' | 'de' | 'germany' | 'dj' | 'djibouti' | 'dk' |
    'denmark' | 'dm' | 'dominica' | 'do' | 'dominican republic' | 'dz' | 'algeria' | 'ec' | 'ecuador' | 'ee' |
    'estonia' | 'eg' | 'egypt' | 'eh' | 'western sahara' | 'er' | 'eritrea' | 'es' | 'spain' | 'et' | 'ethiopia' |
    'eu' | 'european union' | 'fi' | 'finland' | 'fj' | 'fiji' | 'fk' | 'falkland islands' | 'fm' | 'micronesia' |
    'fo' | 'faroe islands' | 'fr' | 'france' | 'ga' | 'gabon' | 'gb' | 'united kingdom' | 'gd' | 'grenada' | 'ge' |
    'georgia' | 'gf' | 'french guiana' | 'gh' | 'ghana' | 'gi' | 'gibraltar' | 'gl' | 'greenland' | 'gm' | 'gambia' |
    'gn' | 'guinea' | 'gp' | 'guadeloupe' | 'gq' | 'equatorial guinea' | 'gr' | 'greece' | 'gs' | 'sandwich islands' |
    'gt' | 'guatemala' | 'gu' | 'guam' | 'gw' | 'guinea-bissau' | 'gy' | 'guyana' | 'hk' | 'hong kong' | 'hm' |
    'heard island' | 'hn' | 'honduras' | 'hr' | 'croatia' | 'ht' | 'haiti' | 'hu' | 'hungary' | 'id' | 'indonesia' |
    'ie' | 'ireland' | 'il' | 'israel' | 'in' | 'india' | 'io' | 'indian ocean territory' | 'iq' | 'iraq' | 'ir' |
    'iran' | 'is' | 'iceland' | 'it' | 'italy' | 'jm' | 'jamaica' | 'jo' | 'jordan' | 'jp' | 'japan' | 'ke' | 'kenya' |
    'kg' | 'kyrgyzstan' | 'kh' | 'cambodia' | 'ki' | 'kiribati' | 'km' | 'comoros' | 'kn' | 'saint kitts and nevis' |
    'kp' | 'north korea' | 'kr' | 'south korea' | 'kw' | 'kuwait' | 'ky' | 'cayman islands' | 'kz' | 'kazakhstan' |
    'la' | 'laos' | 'lb' | 'lebanon' | 'lc' | 'saint lucia' | 'li' | 'liechtenstein' | 'lk' | 'sri lanka' | 'lr' |
    'liberia' | 'ls' | 'lesotho' | 'lt' | 'lithuania' | 'lu' | 'luxembourg' | 'lv' | 'latvia' | 'ly' | 'libya' | 'ma' |
    'morocco' | 'mc' | 'monaco' | 'md' | 'moldova' | 'me' | 'montenegro' | 'mg' | 'madagascar' | 'mh' |
    'marshall islands' | 'mk' | 'macedonia' | 'ml' | 'mali' | 'mm' | 'myanmar' | 'burma' | 'mn' | 'mongolia' | 'mo' |
    'macau' | 'mp' | 'northern mariana islands' | 'mq' | 'martinique' | 'mr' | 'mauritania' | 'ms' | 'montserrat' |
    'mt' | 'malta' | 'mu' | 'mauritius' | 'mv' | 'maldives' | 'mw' | 'malawi' | 'mx' | 'mexico' | 'my' | 'malaysia' |
    'mz' | 'mozambique' | 'na' | 'namibia' | 'nc' | 'new caledonia' | 'ne' | 'niger' | 'nf' | 'norfolk island' | 'ng' |
    'nigeria' | 'ni' | 'nicaragua' | 'nl' | 'netherlands' |     'no' | 'norway' | 'np' | 'nepal' | 'nr' | 'nauru' |
    'nu' | 'niue' | 'nz' | 'new zealand' | 'om' | 'oman' | 'pa' | 'panama' | 'pe' | 'peru' | 'pf' | 'french polynesia' |
    'pg' | 'new guinea' | 'ph' | 'philippines' | 'pk' | 'pakistan' | 'pl' | 'poland' | 'pm' | 'saint pierre' | 'pn' |
    'pitcairn islands' | 'pr' | 'puerto rico' | 'ps' | 'palestine' | 'pt' | 'portugal' | 'pw' | 'palau' | 'py' |
    'paraguay' | 'qa' | 'qatar' | 're' | 'reunion' | 'ro' | 'romania' | 'rs' | 'serbia' | 'ru' | 'russia' | 'rw' |
    'rwanda' | 'sa' | 'saudi arabia' | 'sb' | 'solomon islands' | 'sc' | 'seychelles' | 'gb sct' | 'scotland' | 'sd' |
    'sudan' | 'se' | 'sweden' | 'sg' | 'singapore' | 'sh' | 'saint helena' | 'si' | 'slovenia' | 'sj' | 'svalbard' |
    'jan mayen' | 'sk' | 'slovakia' | 'sl' | 'sierra leone' | 'sm' | 'san marino' | 'sn' | 'senegal' | 'so' |
    'somalia' | 'sr' | 'suriname' | 'st' | 'sao tome' | 'sv' | 'el salvador' | 'sy' | 'syria' | 'sz' | 'swaziland' |
    'tc' | 'caicos islands' | 'td' | 'chad' | 'tf' | 'french territories' | 'tg' | 'togo' | 'th' | 'thailand' | 'tj' |
    'tajikistan' | 'tk' | 'tokelau' | 'tl' | 'timorleste' | 'tm' | 'turkmenistan' | 'tn' | 'tunisia' | 'to' | 'tonga' |
    'tr' | 'turkey' | 'tt' | 'trinidad' | 'tv' | 'tuvalu' | 'tw' | 'taiwan' | 'tz' | 'tanzania' | 'ua' | 'ukraine' |
    'ug' | 'uganda' | 'um' | 'us minor islands' | 'us' | 'america' | 'united states' | 'uy' | 'uruguay' | 'uz' |
    'uzbekistan' | 'va' | 'vatican city' | 'vc' | 'saint vincent' | 've' | 'venezuela' | 'vg' |
    'british virgin islands' | 'vi' | 'us virgin islands' | 'vn' | 'vietnam' | 'vu' | 'vanuatu' | 'gb wls' | 'wales' |
    'wf' | 'wallis and futuna' | 'ws' | 'samoa' | 'ye' | 'yemen' | 'yt' | 'mayotte' | 'za' | 'south africa' | 'zm' |
    'zambia' | 'zw' | 'zimbabwe';
}

declare const Flag: React.StatelessComponent<FlagProps>;

export default Flag;
```

In my project, I have a user model with a country property. I would like to use FlagProps' name property as the type for my country property. I expected the following to work...

```
let UserProps: {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    country: FlagProps.name
}
```

Similarly, I tried to make an Array of country codes...

```
const countryCodes: Array<Flagprops.name> = [...]
```

But in both cases, I get the error **error TS2702: FlagProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.**

Is there any way I can just use selectively use part of the FlagProps interface without overwriting anything?

Answer (score 1):

`FlagProps.name` is a variable, not a type.  You can't use it as your type any more than you can use `UserProps.name` as your type.

What you could do is something like the following:

```
class UserProps {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    get country() {
        return this.flagProps.name;
    }

    set country(value) {
        this.flagProps.name = value;
    }

    private flagProps: FlagProps = { name: 'us' };
}
```

This will infer the underlying type of `FlagProps.name` in the getter and setter.

```
let x = new UserProps();

x.country = 'au';      // Good.  :)
x.country = 'foobar';  // ERROR!
```